# Using SharePoint's REST API to $expand a folder's people field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016, sharepoint-rest-api

I can't quite remember how to expand a field of a folder or file.  Example: I can do something like `Folders/ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member` to expand the role assignments, but I cannot do this for my custom column.

---

### Details

- Document Library has a column called "Authors"
- The column is a multiple *person or group*
- The column appears as an *AuthorsId* field in the JSON response

**REST API URL**:
`/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/<name>/Documents')?$expand=Folders/ListItemAllFields`

**odata=nometadata** (response):

```js
[ { ListItemAllFields:
     { FileSystemObjectType: 1,
       ...,
       AuthorsId: [ 2, 3, 5, 8 ]
     },
   Name: 'My Folder Name',
   ItemCount: 20,
   ...
  },
  ...
]
```

---

### Failures

This is just more info in attempts I've made that result in `Bad Request` failures:

- Folders/ListItemAllFields/Authors/Id
- Folders/ListItemAllFields/Authors

`Folders/ListItemAllFields/AuthorsId` does not result in failure, but doesn't expand the resulting array either

Comment: Are you able to use the list endpoint instead? Something like `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items?$expand=Authors&$select=Authors/Title&$filter=Authors ne null` seems like it should work.

Comment: @Thriggle sorry I never responded. I didn’t see the notification or accidentally clicked early and never came back to it. I’m not sure where this stands. I don’t think I found a solution and queried siteusers, but I am not positive about that. I’ll have to check (if I remember) when I return to that code, probably in the new year. Thanks for your comment all the same!